# How to move the legend in Seaborn FacetGrid outside of the plot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have the following code:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="Type", hue="Name", size=3, aspect=3)
g = g.map(sns.plt.plot, "Volume", "Index")
g.add_legend()
sns.plt.show()
```

This results in the following plot:

[image]

How can I move the legend outside of the plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mwaskom's comment above, this is a bug in OS X. Indeed switching to another backend solves the issue.

For instance, I put this into my `matplotlibrc`:

```
backend : TkAgg   # use Tk with antigrain (agg) rendering
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by resizing the plots:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="Type", hue="Name", size=3, aspect=3)
g = g.map(sns.plt.plot, "Volume", "Index")
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    box = ax.get_position()
    ax.set_position([box.x0,box.y0,box.width*0.9,box.height])

sns.plt.legend(loc='center left',bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5))
sns.plt.show()
```

Example:

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

# more informative values
condition = tips['smoker'] == 'Yes'
tips['smoking_status'] = ''
tips.loc[condition,'smoking_status'] = 'Smoker'
tips.loc[~condition,'smoking_status'] = 'Non-Smoker'

g = sns.FacetGrid(tips,row='sex',hue='smoking_status',size=3,aspect=3)
g = g.map(plt.scatter,'total_bill','tip')
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    box = ax.get_position()
    ax.set_position([box.x0,box.y0,box.width*0.85,box.height])

sns.plt.legend(loc='upper left',bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5))
sns.plt.show()
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'plt'. obsolete?

Comment: @Rockbar, just drop 'sns'--see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989743/sns-plt-show-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: No, this is not sufficient for seaborn 0.10.0. Matplotlib doesn't find "handles with labels found to put in legend". One has to use `g._legend`.

Answer (score 4):

Following Seaborn documentation you can add the arg `legend_out=True` to your call and that should fix the problem

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html

Your code would then look like

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="Type", hue="Name", size=3, aspect=3, legend_out=True)
g = (g.map(plt.plot, "Volume", "Index").add_legend())
plt.show()
```