# sns.plt.show() not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Tried to call sns.plt.show() in my script, but got the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/vm/PycharmProjects/SPCP/test.py", line 6, in 
>     sns.plt.show()
>   AttributeError: module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'plt'

Recently upgraded to Anaconda 5. Is there another way to call "plt.show()" without importing matplotlib.pyplot as plt?

Note: sns.plt.show() used to work previously

Comment: Just `plt.show()`. `importing seaborn as sns` will cause seaborn to set the style automatically.

Comment: See dupe. Apparently, doing that is a bug on older versions they've fixed. You have no choice I'm afraid.