# Hue in Seaborn plots covers the main plot...creating problem

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn, scatter-plot

Whenever I try to use the hue feature in seaborn it works fine if the column used in Hue has lesser values. But in case of larger number of values it covers/shadows the main plot. Is there anyway to keep/position the hue column value details not on the top of the main plot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe easiest solution is just to enlarge fig size, as plot will take smaller relative size.

Seaborn's doesn't handle well with legends in my opinion. You can edit legend using `matplotlib` function: [matplotlib's legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html)

Some possible solutions:

1. Move legend outside: [Move legend outside figure in seaborn tsplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490740/move-legend-outside-figure-in-seaborn-tsplot)
2. resizing the plot: [How to move the legend in Seaborn FacetGrid outside of the plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773560/how-to-move-the-legend-in-seaborn-facetgrid-outside-of-the-plot)
3. smaller text in legend(see first answer): [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)